# Edit bar button doesn't work as intended

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my table view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method I have the standard line `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editBarButtonItem()` to add the Edit bar button.

When my table view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController` (and thus has the table view as its `view` property), the Edit button works normally and triggers a change of table view's `editing` state.

But after I had rewritten my table view controller so it now subclasses `UIViewController` (implementing `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols), the Edit button has stopped working. It still switches between Edit and Done, but no longer changes table view's `editing` state.

How to fix that? Should I implement `setEditing: animated:` method in my view controller? If yes, could you post some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple. I just had to call `super` and update table view's `editing` state.

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```